# Can we convert this For-loop into LINQ?

Tags: linq

Can we convert this For-loop into LINQ expresion; both in Query Syntax and Method Syntax  ?

```
List<INode> sds = new List<INode>();

foreach (INode n in lnd)
{
    foreach(string s in Pages)
    {
        if (n.NiceUrl == s)
        {
            sds.Add(n);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? It's readable. You won't get any performance benefit.

Comment: Try Resharper. It will do this for you in one click. Strictly taken, the correct answer to your question is **yes**. If you ask "please do this for me" it might be helpful to show what you tried and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

```
from n in lnd
from s in Pages
where n.NiceUrl == s
select n
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sds = lnd.Join(Pages, n => n.NiceUrl, p => p, (n, p) => n).ToList();
```

Comment: Perhaps a little explanation about how your code works would be helpful to other readers?

Answer (score 0):

```
Pages.Where(y => lnd.Select(x => x.NiceUrl).Contains(y)).Tolist();
```

lnd.Select(x => x.NiceUrl) part can be replaced with a HashSet.